# Add extra margin (on right) to a pdf without losing outline?

Tags: linux, pdf

I would like to take an existing pdf and make it's right size wider (add white space), so that I can add my own hand-drawn annotations to it with my graphics tablet (loaded in Xournal++).

So far I found a way to do it via pdfcrop:

```
pdfcrop --margin '0 0 400 0' in.pdf out.pdf
```

But I lose the outline/bookmark section on the right.

Does anyone know of a way?
(A linux app/cmd is preferred, but I'd be open to exploring online or windows/osx tools if anyone knows..).

Answer (score 6):

Since I lack reputation to comment, I would like to expand on Yuta's answer here.
To add extra margin, use the following command of [pdfCropMargins](https://pypi.org/project/pdfCropMargins/):

```
pdf-crop-margins -o out.pdf -p 100 -a4 $left $bottom $right $top in.pdf
```

The units are in BP (= 1/72 inch). Positive numbers shrink the margin and negative numbers expand it. For example, to expand the right margin by 1 inch, you would use `-a4 0 0 -72 0`.

Without `-p 100` pdfCropMargins always shrinks the original margins to 10% before applying the absolute offsets from the `a4` parameter.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: Use `pdf-crop-margins -g "2-4,6-10" …`, for example, to modify only the pages in the specified range.

Answer (score 2):

[By author]

After much research [1], I found a tool that works on Linux. 
It's free to try but I think it needs a 50$ license. I was able to use it to add a margin to my pdf and preserve the outline.

I have not been able to find a free tool. If someone does find one, please feel free to post an additional answer and I'd be happy to try it out.

If of help to anyone stumbling into the same problem, the tool I've used is Master pdf editor:

https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/

Document -> Page Layout -> 'width'.

(On RHEL/Fedora I had to install qt5-qtsvg library to get it to work.).

**[1] Linux tools I've tried:**
(as per https://www.tecmint.com/best-pdf-page-cropping-tools-for-linux/)

- Briss - can't expand margin, only shrink.
- pdfcrop - can expand, but looses table of content (as described by question).
- Pdf Shuffler - doesn't crop, only re-arrange/delete pages.
- Evince/Okular - Don't seem to have the ability to edit page layout/crop.
- pdf-quench - couldn't get it to work.
- KCrop - Can make a page smaller, but not bigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pdfCropMargins
pdf-crop-margins sample.pdf -o sample_cropped.pdf
```

The above worked for me. It crops `sample.pdf` without losing outlines.
It should work for adding extra margins, which I did not try though.

Answer (score 0):

This script starts by creating a temporary PDF in A4 format, ensuring it fits the page. Then, it adjusts the size by increasing the width and shifting the content to the left. Feel free to customize the parameters to match your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if an input PDF file is provided as an argument
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <input.pdf>"
    exit 1
fi

input_pdf="$1"

# Check if the input PDF file exists
if [ ! -f "$input_pdf" ]; then
    echo "Error: The input PDF file '$input_pdf' does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

# Extract the base name of the input file (without the extension)
inputname=$(basename "$input_pdf" .pdf)

# Create temp_a4.pdf
gs -o temp_a4.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dPDFFitPage -f "$input_pdf"

# Wait for temp_a4.pdf to be created
while [ ! -f temp_a4.pdf ]; do
    sleep 1
done

# Create output.pdf with increased width and content translated to the left
gs -o "${inputname}-wide.pdf" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1100 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -c "<</Install {0 0 translate 0 -150 translate}>> setpagedevice" -f temp_a4.pdf


# Cleanup temp_a4.pdf
rm temp_a4.pdf

echo "Output PDF: ${inputname}-wide.pdf"
```

Usage: rename the script as you prefer (a.e addwidth.sh)
Run: `sh ./addwidth.sh input.pdf`